# Is there any way I can debug my hosted applicaion in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Is it possible to debug my hosted web application on server sing VS 2012.

I tried using attching process from tools, but break points are not getting enabled.

Any tools or suggestions on this?

Thanks,

Naresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading the remote debugger:

[Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30674)

[How to: Set Up Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx)

Comment: Can you please also suggest to debug open source C# libraries. Thanks.

Comment: I really don't have any idea to debug the libraries while we debugging the client applications.

Comment: If you have the source, it should be no different that debugging code in your project. Caveat: I haven't tried this remotely, so...

Comment: I don't have the source of library. I just have the library.

Comment: You can't debug code you don't have (you can decompile it). Work with what you have and narrow the problem down in your own code first.